# Use Named Column in Where Clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having an issue saying that "total amount" is an invalid identifier on my where clause. I want to use the "total amount" and compare it to another number that is determine in the *insert code here* section but cannot figure out how to properly set up the first part of the where.

When naming a column like I did do you not use the name when wanting to use that column in a where?

```
 SELECT desc, TO_CHAR(SUM(price * quantity), '99999.00') AS "total amount"
 FROM items i
 JOIN line_items li
   ON i.item_id = li.item_id
 WHERE "total amount" > 
   (*insert code here*);
```

Comment: @ch2019 i dont understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

First, you want a `having` clause, not a `where` cause.

Second, your query is missing a `group by`.

Third, you cannot use a column alias in `where` or `having` in Oracle.  Instead, you need to repeat the expression, use a subquery, or use a CTE.

For this example, I would recommend:

```
SELECT i.desc,
       TO_CHAR(SUM(i.price * li.quantity), '99999.00') AS "total amount"
FROM items i JOIN
     line_items li
     ON i.item_id = li.item_id
GROUP BY i.desc
HAVING SUM(i.price * li.quantity) > ?;
```

Notes:

- The `?` is for whatever the comparison value or expression is.
- Your query is missing a `GROUP BY`.
- `desc` is a *really* bad name for a column, because it is a SQL keyword (think `ORDER BY`).
- Get in the good habit of qualifying all column references in your query to identify the table they come from.  I have made educated guesses for this query.
- You wouldn't want to do a comparison on `"total amount"` anyway, because it is a string and you (no doubt) want a comparison of numbers (so `10 > 9` but `'10' < '9'`.

Answer (score 0):

Derived value should always come in brackets.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT desc, TO_CHAR(SUM(price * quantity), '99999.00') AS "total amount"
    FROM items i
    JOIN line_items li ON i.item_id = li.item_id
) AMT
WHERE "total amount" > '' /* YOUR VALUE HERE */
```